# how to use / import a Lotus Notes public key into Thunderbird

Tags: certificate, smime

A colleague from abroad who uses Lotus Notes sent me his "internet certificate" (i.e. public key), so I could import it into my own e-mail client. Unfortunately I do not recognise the format (neither does Thunderbird nor Outlook). The key consists of octets and starts with something like

```
    03004502 F725826A 10G01626 G002A6FA
```

What kind of format is this and how to convert it into a format which can be imported by a S/MIME client?
For more details about the "internet certificate" see this [IBM howto](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/steps-obtain-import-ssl-certificate-encrypted-mail), chapter 13.

Comment: Did your colleague send it as an attachment? He is required to export his certificate as described in [this knowledge base](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_8.5.3/com.ibm.notes85.client.doc/sec_cert_inter_imp_t.html) rather than just copying it from the contact record.

Comment: @not2savvy I suppose this is the main problem. Thanks for this link! I searched quite for a while but came not across this one. Will forward it to my colleague.

Comment: @not2savvy  I am afraid the howto you proposed will not solve the problem because it is about exporting the pkcs12, i.e. the private key. I need the public key (e.g. as .p7b)

Comment: It should be possible to select base-64 (pem) format instead of the PKCS#12 default. However, PKCS#12 ist just the format, and need not necessarily include the private key which can be included or excluded from the export options.

Comment: @not2savvy I advised my colleague to try this and to look for an corresponding export option. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert Lotus Notes to Thunderbird try this free tool to easily convert Lotus Notes (NSF) file to Thunderbird(mbox)format.
[Visit here](https://www.spikevare.com/lotus-notes/thunderbird/)

Comment: @steaww I do not see how your mentioned tool could convert certificates - it's all about mail conversion, isn't it?

Comment: It converts Data